# If I were to make an Application Config xml file in java where should I put it?

Tags: java

If I were to create an application configuration xml file should it be inside the src folder or should it be in the root?

Comment: Neither. It should be inside the resources folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be in the CLASSPATH when you run.

Where you put it during development is less important, but I wouldn't put it in source.  I usually create a /context or /resources folder and put all context XML there.  When I build my package, I make sure the contents of that folder are moved to the CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 4):

It just need to be in your classpath so that your code/container can find.

Comment: +1, ideally not at the root level else it may clash with something

Answer (score 0):

I nice spot for the configuration is also the `META-INF/<group>/<artifact>/` folder.